# how to add multiple selected items from CheckedListBox to SQL table in Visual Basic (VS2019)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I currently have the following that allows me to select whats in my CheckedListBox and it displays in a message box popup

```
public Sub CheckedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If CheckedListBox1.Items.Count > 0 Then
        Dim Items As New List(Of String)
        For Index As Int32 = 0 To (CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1)
            If CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(Index) Then
                Items.Add(CStr(CheckedListBox1.Items.Item(Index)))
            End If
        Next
        Dim Result = String.Join(",", Items.ToArray)
        'MessageBox.Show(Result)


    Else
      ' Nothing checked
    End If
```

Now i need that result set to be loaded to the parameter defined from my stored procedure :

```
   ' Add Multiple selections to Brand column in SQL. 
 sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SKU", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100))
 sqlCommand.Parameters("@SKU").Value = CheckedListBox1.Text
```

Works fine with one selected value only.
but I am needing it to load the Dim Result into the @SKU parameter.
assuming example: sqlCommand.Parameters("@SKU").Value = (Result)

Regards

Comment: If you only have one parameter then how do you expect to pass in multiple values? Is the SQL code splitting that one parameter value into multiple parts?

Comment: The `SelectedIndexChanged` event is obviously the wrong place to be doing any of that. Selection in a `CheckedListBox` is exactly the same as in a regular `ListBox`. If `CheckOnClick` is `False`, which it is by default, then the two are completely unrelated. The `ItemCheck` event handler is the more appropriate place to work with checked items but be aware that that event is raised before the state of an item changes.

Comment: You cannot expect your SP to magically split multiple values by comma. Either you have to code it there (than it is no vb .net issue) or you create a table valued type and send it as e.g. DataTable. You can than query your result in the SP as it was a table. (I recommend it that way because it is much more cleaner)

Comment: but the result set defined in here: (Result) already joins the checked items from the checkedlistbox example: itemA,itemB,itemC

it already shows in 'MessageBox.Show(Result) - but i need that same result set to be directed to the variable @SKU

Comment: As I said you can go with `sqlCommand.Parameters("@SKU").Value = Result`. But than you have to split those result values in your stored procedure again.

Comment: and that is the problem - sqlCommand.Parameters("@SKU").Value = Result. it does not work :(

Comment: Hi. I figured it out.
i allowed the Result set to load to a Label1 - 

            Dim Result = String.Join(",", Items.ToArray)
            'MessageBox.Show(Result)
            Label1.Text = Result

then used the Label1.text to send to the variable through to my stored proc.

sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SKU", SqlDbType.VarChar,100))
sqlCommand.Parameters("@SKU").Value = Label1.Text

Comment: Yes, that will give you one big string but is that what your really want? What kind of command is this? A Select, Insert, Update or Delete? That would be an oddly designed database that would have several SKU's stuffed into a single column in a single row.

Comment: Also you have to be careful regarding the length of the string. Your param is defined as varchar(100) but with several SKUs it could exceed the maximum length

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you could give a reply and mark your reply as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I allowed the Result set to load into a `Label1`:

```
Dim Result = String.Join(",", Items.ToArray) 
Label1.Text = Result
```

Then I used the `Label1.text` to send through a variable to my stored proc:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SKU", SqlDbType.VarChar,100)) 
sqlCommand.Parameters("@SKU").Value = Label1.Text
```

Comment: That's great! You can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. This will help others facing the same problem.

Comment: Thank you for formatting correctly. Was my first time.